# How does remote aar work in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Previously, to use Sherlock Action Bar in my project, I need to download entire Sherlock Action Bar source code and include it as project library.

Now, by using Android Studio, I just need to following line in my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

My guess is, Android Studio will go to a remote repository to download the library

1. How can I know what is the remote repository?
2. How can I know what other aar found in remote repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository you use is listed in `repositories{}` closure. If you created the project from Android Studio template, it will be `jcenter()`.

[JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) is [Bintray](https://bintray.com/)'s Java components repository. It's the largest repository out there and you can use the search to see which packages are in there. Once you found the package you're interesting in, you can copy–paste the gradle declaration to add it to your build, review, subscribe to update notifications and more.

Comment: Wow. You're the creator of Bintray!